# Spectral theorem for unital $C^{*}$-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ac.commutative-algebra, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^{*}$-algebra and $a \in A$ be normal, with spectrum $\sigma(a)$. Let $B = C^{*}(a)$ be the $C^{*}$-algebra generated by $1$ and $a$, which is abelian. Let $\hat{B}$ be the space of all homomorphisms $\chi: B \to \mathbb{C}$ with the weak* topology, which makes it a compact Hausdorff topological space.

Gelfand Isomorphism Theorem states that $\varphi: B \to C(\hat{B})$ is an isometric $*$-isomorphism. Moreover, $\hat{a}: \hat{B} \to \sigma(a) \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a homeomorphism, so that $\hat{B} \cong \sigma(a)$.

On one hand, given a positive functional $\omega: C(\hat{B}) \to \mathbb{C}$, Riesz Representation Theorem states that there exists a unique regular Borel measure $\mu$ on $\sigma(a)$ such that:
$$\omega(f) = \int_{\hat{B}}f(\chi)d\mu_{\omega}(\chi).$$

On the other hand, given a function $g \in C(\sigma(a))$, there is a natural identification $g \mapsto  g\circ \hat{a}$ from $C(\sigma(a))$ to $C(\hat{B})$. Hence, each $\mu_{\omega}$ induces a new measure $\nu_{\omega}$ on $\sigma(a)$ by using $\hat{a}^{-1}$ as a push-forward.

By the abstract change of variables formula, it must hold:
$$\int_{\hat{B}} (g\circ \hat{a})(\chi)d\mu_{\omega}(\chi) = \int_{\sigma(a)}g(z)d\nu_{\omega}(z) \tag{1}\label{1}$$

My question is: can we extend this analysis to $A$ instead of $B$ (and $\hat{A}$ instead of $\hat{B}$ and so on) when $A$ is abelian? I don't think so because, in this case, $\hat{a}$ is not a homeomorphism between $\hat{A}$ and $\sigma(a)$, but I couldn't tell if a general version of formula (\ref{1}) holds from the literature I know on the topic.

Comment: The question is a bit vague as stated.  Suppose $a=1$ so that $\sigma(a)$ and $\hat B$ are points.  What kind of formula do you have in mind instead of (1) in this case?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Although I started the analysis with an arbitrary $C^{*}$-algebra and studied the subalgebra $B= C^{*}(a)$, which is abelian. My question is: if $A$ was abelian, does the analysis follow for all $A$ instead of for an abelian subalgebra of it?

Comment: So what do you want to play the role of σ(a) in the absence of a?  The most natural analogue of σ(a) is just Â itself, so your formula becomes a tautology.  Unless you have a different formula in mind, which is why I asked the above question.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov what I meant is the following. Suppose $A$ is an abelian $C^{*}$-star and $a \in A$ be normal, with $\sigma(a)$ its spectrum. Can we prove formula (\ref{1}) in this case, when $B$ is replaced by $A$? The only difference is that, in my post, $A$ was not abelian, so I have to restrict to $B=C^{*}(a)$ to use Gelfand's Isomorphism Theorem. But when $A$ is abelian, do the same formulas hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that (1) continues to hold when B is replaced by A,
it suffices (by linearity and density of step functions) to consider only the case when g is the characteristic function of some measurable subset S of σ(a).

Indeed, in this case the right side equals the ν-measure of S, whereas the left side equals the μ-measure of the â-preimage of S.  Since ν was defined as the â-pushforward of μ, this equality holds by definition.

Comment: Dmitri, thank you for your answer. I was puzzled because, in the analysis of my post, I used the fact that $\hat{B} \cong \sigma(a)$. But if $A$ is abelian and $a \in A$ is normal, I believe the same analysis provide an isomorphism $\hat{A}\cong \sigma(a)$, right? And then formula (\ref{1}) follows from my analysis, which justifies your answer.

Comment: @MathMath:  No, Â is isomorphic to σ(a) if and only if a generates A as a C*-algebra.  Otherwise, you just have a continuous map Â→σ(a) provided by the Gelfand transformation, but it is no longer a homeomorphism.